# opening the same dialog from a list in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog

I have a listActivity with many items.

For each item, I want to open the same popup while sending an item id\position\other

info object unique to that item.

But basically all the time I open the exact same popup.

Its buttons will send the extra unique data to the server.

I have read few tutorials, and saw a dialog is usually opened like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
dialog.setTitle("Title...");

// set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

dialog.show();
}
```

I think it's more readable to create a different file to the dialog.

like this:

```
public class SocialActionsDialog extends Dialog {

public SocialActionsDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

Context mContext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.social_actions);
    setTitle("Title...");
}
```

but then I get a syntax error on the `OnCreate`.

Is it common and good practice to create new file? and if so- how to do it properly?

is it more efficient somehow - just showing the same dialog instead of initializing a new one each time? or is both ways the same?

Comment: Better see DialogFragment.
What syntax error you got in onCreate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the syntax error, make sure you are importing the `R` class from your app and not the Android SDK class `R` resources.

For an experienced programmer your instinct is to move the dialog to a separate file, especially if it contains a lot of code. And that can be the right decision at times.

However, it is often convenient to have the dialog as an embedded class or to just create it inline (as in your example) because then it is within the scope of your activity and can access your state variables and protected methods on the `Activity` itself.

So you end up passing all this information to the dialog if you have it in a separate file, and at some point it just isn't worth it because the code becomes more complex and less maintainable.